# EF 4.1 ComException on DbContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: exception, entity-framework-4.1, savechanges

I'm using EF 4.1. Whenever an error occurs during the execution of a DbContext operation like SaveChanges() I consistently receive a rather cryptic error message: **System.Exception._ComPlusExceptionCode -532462766**. Obviously this is not very helpful for finding out what went wrong. A quick Google search for ComPlusException in context with EF returned no meaningful results.

Any ideas why I receive this error message and what can be done in order to get a more descriptive error feedback would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Code:

```
    public void InsertTarget(Target target)
    {
        try
        {
            _tgrContext.Targets.Add(target);
            _tgrContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem here:

[complusexceptions in net](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/complusexceptions-in-net/#comment-345)

In short: Visual Studio decodes the complusexception code into the actual error message on click at the red error quation mark in the VS code editor. I hardly ever use this visual indicatior, so I guess it was easy to miss for me.